# why does forEach function gives wrong output?

Tags: javascript

```
Challenge
Using the JavaScript language, have the function
```

ArrayAdditionI(arr) take the array of numbers stored in arr and return //the string true if any combination of numbers in the array can be added //up to equal the largest number in the array, otherwise return the //string false. For example: if arr contains [4, 6, 23, 10, 1, 3] the //output should return true because 4 + 6 + 10 + 3 = 23. The array will //not be empty, will not contain all the same elements, and may contain //negative numbers.
    // Sample Test Cases
    // Input:5,7,16,1,2
    // Output:"false"
    //
    // Input:3,5,-1,8,12
    // Output:"true"

```
    function findLargest(array){
      var largest = array[0];

      array.forEach(function(num){
         if(num > largest){
           largest = num;
         }
      });
      return largest;
    }

    function ArrayAdditionI(array){
      var largest = findLargest(array);
      var index = array.indexOf(largest);
      array.splice(index,1);

      array.forEach(function(num,idx){
        var sum = 0;
        for(var j=0; j<array.length; j++){
          if(num === array[j]){
            continue;
          }else{
            sum+=array[j];
          }
        }
        if(sum === largest){
          return true;
        }
      });
    return false;
    }

    console.log(ArrayAdditionI([4, 6, 23, 10, 1, 3]));
```

Hello everyone!!,
The output of this ArrayAdditionI function should be true, but for some unknown reason it is returning false.However, I found out that it's because of the forEach function because when I used forLoop instead, it worked fine. Does anyone know why whenever I use the forEach it gives me false output? and why is this happening ??

Comment: if(sum === largest){  return true;} else return false

Comment: `return`ing from within the `forEach` will not return from your `ArrayAdditionI` function, merely from the `forEach` function itself

Comment: `function findLargest(array){ return Math.max.apply( null, array ); }`

Comment: change `forEach()` to `some()`, and put the `return` behind it... `return array.some(function(num, idx)...`

Comment: What is your goal, really? To return true if the largest number is greater than the sum of the rest?

Comment: my goal is to know that if any sum of the array elements are equal to the largest number in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my goal is to know that if any sum of the array elements are equal to the largest number in the array.

You can do it using:

```
function containsSumToMaximum( array ){
  array.sort( function(a,b){ return a < b ? -1 : 1; } );
  var max = array.pop();
  for ( var i = 3; i < 2 << array.length; i++ )
  {
    var sum   = 0,
        count = 0;
    for ( var j = 0; j < array.length; j++ )
    {
      if ( i & (2 << j) )
      {
        sum += array[j];
        count++;
      }
      if ( sum > max )
        break;
    }
    if ( sum == max && count > 1 )
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

For an array of `n` elements there are `2^n -1` ways of summing one-or-more of those elements. The algorithm above just does a brute-force search of all those possible sums and considers whether each sums to the maximum value and that the sum is made up of two-or-more elements.

Answer (score 2):

Add this:

```
var found = false; // <--- new
array.forEach(function(num,idx){
```

And this:

```
      if(sum === largest){
          found = true; // <--- new
      }

  });

  return found; // <--- new
```

As @Hamms said in the comments, a `return` inside a `forEach` will only return within the loop and will **not** return the outer function `ArrayAdditionI`

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f782dcps/